# Binary clock_nanosleep "bypass"

Tags: c, binaryfiles

i'm currently in programming studies and do CTFs in my spare time to get a few extra skills.

Right now i'm facing a binary (i dont have the source code but could ghidra it) which:

- putchar a single char
- clock_nanosleep for X seconds
- putchar a single char
- clock_nanosleep for Y seconds
- ...

(I've strace the binary and saw that the binary uses "clock_nanosleep" with "CLOCK_REALTIME")

My question is: Is there a way to execute the binary while skipping the "clock_nanosleep" ?

My guesses:

1. Maybe block him the time.h lib so he cant execute "clock_nanosleep" ?
2. Maybe modify the "CLOCK_REALTIME" so that the program thinks the time have passed and finishes the "clock_nanosleep" ?

Extra informations:

File :  `ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=5eca63735d90098f20f45ca172e242372994976e, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped`

Strings : `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 libc.so.6`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `LD_PRELOAD` to neuter the `clock_nanosleep` call:

```
#include <time.h>

int clock_nanosleep(clockid_t clockid, int flags,
                    const struct timespec *request,
                    struct timespec *remain) {
    return 0;
}
```

compile with

```
> gcc inject.c -shared -fPIC -o inject.so
```

and run with

```
> LD_PRELOAD=$PWD/inject.so ./program
```

this will effectively disable calls to `clock_nanosleep` by making them return immediately.

---

If you don't want to run your program under `LD_PRELOAD`, you can get creative with solutions - for instance, patch every opcode that calls `clock_nanosleep` with `nop`s, which is automatable with Ghidra scripting.

Comment: Worked for a part. (I've added "sleep", "usleep" and "nanosleep" just un case)
Now i'll have to understand why there is still something happening between the nexts writes.